# How can I export dynamically added event listeners to a static HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

So I'm building a website creator. Users can add drag divs around a page and add onClick event listeners to these divs. I would like the user to be able to 'publish' the website, which will save all the  in an html file along with their onClick event listeners.

To "export" the user's website, I called the jquery `.html()` function:
`$('#builder').html()`

Which contains all the html of all the divs, but none of the event listeners :(.

As you can see here, the click listener is attached to the img, but the 'onclick' attribute is not set in the HTML.

[image]

Is there a way to modify the `onclick` attribute in the HTML tag itself? I just want to preserve event listeners in a static HTML file.

Comment: you'll need to generate JavaScript that calls `addEventListener()`.

Comment: great idea thank you. is there any other way though? is there no way to just modify the 'onclick' attribute and inline function in the HTML tag itself, using javascript?

Comment: If you use `element.setAttribute("onclick", "some code")` then it should show up in the HTML tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: element.setAttribute worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged jQuery, here is the jQuery solution. You can use [attr](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp) to set any HTML attribute.

`$(element).attr('onclick', 'your magical code');`

Cheers!